# Can someone explain switching in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I just started learning Objective C and I don't understand switches.
Can someone please explain them to me?

Thanks

Comment: tag this [tag:objective-c] instead of [tag:c#]

Comment: Any textbook or tutorial website should be able to do this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=objective+c+switch+statement

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement

Comment: To closers: sure the question might be boderline, but its not really asking for code. Switch statements do confuse some due to the model being computed goto and not multiway selection. But hey I'm biased as a I wrote an answer before the close vote was up ;-)

Comment: @CRD: So if someone comes along "Can someone explain programming" would you also jump in?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Of course not, but its about balance, and flexibility. This is a small issue which does confuse due to the two models different programming languages use. As I say, its borderline, but maybe this time we should err on helping the OP here (and others who find this Q in the future) rather than sending them elsewhere.

Comment: @CRD: it is not even clear, what it meant. it could be `switch … case`. but also it could be `UISwitch`. Or maybe switching some threads?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - I think `UISwitch` is more of a stretch than `switch`, and someone has added the `switch-statement` tag. Sometimes we can afford to be generous and give the benefit of the doubt. Well, I've said my bit, your call folks.

Comment: Op is talking of switches. Not switch statement or switch case. Even in a switch statement there is no plural of switch. This is a bad and ambiguous question. You can be as generous as you want. I will close such question as I assume that even a SO newbie can post better question and it is his duty. OP can come back and increase the quality. But because people per-maturely answer, quality will not be increased and finally the question will get deleted as poor question. Is that generosity?

Comment: sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch statement is meant to be used in place of if else statements

For example

```
int a =4;

if(a == 1)
    doSomething();
else if(a == 2)
    doSomethingElse();
else if(a == 3)
    BLAH();
else
     CaseUnaccountedFor();
```

Is equivalent to

```
int a =4;

switch(a) {
case 1:
    doSomething();
    break;
case 2:
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
case 3:
    BLAH();
    break;
default:
   CaseUnaccountedFor();
    break;
}
```

If one of the cases is a match, the switch statement is not automatically exited which is why there's a break statement at the end of each case. The case 'default' matches every other case besides the ones you explicitly list.

Answer (score 0):

A switch-statement in (Objective-)C (and other members of the C family) is a *computed goto* (or *jump*/*branch*).

An expression of some *scalar type* - basically an integer type or a type which trivially converts to an integer - is evaluated and its value use to select a *label* to branch to within a block of code.

Each label is a constant value, indicated by `case <value>:`; or `default:`, which is used if no label exists for the value of the expression. The labels themselves may occur in any order within the block of code.

Once the jump has occurred execution flow continues as normal through the rest of the code block, including past any labels that are encountered. Passing from one section of code prefixed by a label into a following piece of code prefix by another label is typically referred to as "fall through".

To prevent fall through the statement `break;` may be used. This is a branching statement which jumps to the end of code block. By using one `break` at the end of each label-prefixed group of statements within the code block a kind of multi-choice selection construct is formed - the value of the expression in the `switch` selects one, and one only, of the label-prefixed statement groups. This is a very common pattern, and indeed some other programming languages provide this pattern explicitly and do not support the C family's computed goto model at all.

As there is but a single block of code in a `switch` the individual label-prefixed statement groups cannot contain variable declarations which are local to just that group - the scope of any declaration in any group is the whole code block. This issue often confuses first-time users as the seemingly close parallel, the `if`/`then`/`else` statement, contains *two* statement blocks and therefore the scope of variable declarations does not extend across both branches.

The declaration scope issue can simply be addressed by enclosing the group of statements following a label in a block (a braced sequence of statements), giving the outline:

```
case value:
   {
      sequence of statements including declarations - scope limited to this block
   }
   break;
```

Using this model gives the closest equivalent of other languages multi-choice selection statements.

Finally, a `switch` statement is usually more efficient and an equivalent sequence of `if`/`then`/`else` statements - both in execution and in readability.

HTH.